# When should you add another answer instead of adding to your previous answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

Suppose I give a solution to a problem in an answer and then later on I think of a different method to solve the same problem.

> Should I edit my old answer and include the second method, or should I add another answer?

I don't think I've ever seen a user give more than one answer to a question, but maybe they should have.

Comment: Here's a recent example of mine: [answer 1](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/471651/139); [answer 2](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/471664/139).  Answer 1 would work in general, but is less slick than answer 2 (which is more ad hoc).

Comment: Related (duplicate?): http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/treatment-of-multiple-answers-by-same-user-to-same-question

Comment: Also seemingly related/duplicate (but with a less "searchable" title): http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10205/multiple-answers

Comment: See also - finally? :-) - http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6525/whats-wrong-with-a-user-posting-different-and-independent-answers-to-a-question

Comment: I have on occasion given as many as three approaches in the same "answer." Works fine.

Comment: I have also given two answers to the a question: [answer 1](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/385826/1551), [answer 2](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/385916/1551). I tried to avoid proofs by contradiction and came up with two proofs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the second answer is of a different nature, using different tools, etc, I would say there would be no problem adding a second answer. However, if the second answer is simply a slight change to the original answer, I would incorporate those changes into another section of that answer.

Of course there are shades of grey involved here and others may feel that a separate answer is too close, so don't be too surprised by some downvotes. You can always improve the second answer by adding some different ideas or methods to it.

Comment: How many shades of grey?

Comment: @DanielRust $\geq 50$$$$$I usually add sections to my answers with title **Method 1** etc.

Answer (score 4):

One reason against distinct answers is that they might seem like attempts to gain more reputation for answering a single question. But in those cases where two answers means approximately twice as much work as a single answer would have been, I have no problem at all with that kind of reward. And having multiple answers allows independent voting on them, so this is a great way to let the community decide which of them is more useful.

I'm using this approach myself, with [some](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/452130/35416) [posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/329469/35416) here on Math SE, and [several](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11421420/1468366) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11427840/1468366) [with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11347574/1468366) [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11344408/1468366) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11482113/1468366) on Stack Overflow, sometimes with interesting vote distributions.